# How to save the state of PowerShell in Windows 10 as to continue with it later?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, state-saving

[image: Powershell]

Let's say I'm done for the day and shutting down my laptop. Now, how can I save the PowerShell window shown in the image so that I can continue from the same state of the PowerShell window tomorrow along with all the outputs?

Tomorrow when I open the PowerShell, it should have the same path along with all its output.

Comment: use a virtual machine and take a snapshot?

Comment: No @Cid , a snapshot will not work as I have to continue working on it tomorrow.

Comment: Yes it will, I'm using VMs everyday and save states like this

Comment: Which VM you are using?

Comment: VMWare Workstation, but any VM tool should allow you to save snapshots/states

Comment: These VMs consume a lot of resources and I have a very decent laptop. So is there some other way?

Comment: Why not simply use [sleep/hibernate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-pc-2941d165-7d0a-a5e8-c5ad-8c972e8e6eff)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why do have the requirement?

Comment: @iRon you know how frequently windows 10 requires restarting. I'm continuously installing and deleting new things.

Comment: @alexzelaya it's very painful everytime to start the process from scratch

Comment: What's so painful? Is there a list of manual things that could maybe be automated?

Comment: See everyone has their own requirements. I don't want to waste my time every day doing the same tasks which can be automated.